Triggering Event for Incoming call using sip js in react native
I am using sip js for call functionality in react native. For the incoming call, How can we trigger the event in sip js when the call is initiated? I can hear the ringtone but couldn't make the incoming screen module appear in phone.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated.
This is the event session:
// Incoming or outgoing event
    this.coolPhone.on('newRTCSession', (e: any) => {
      log(`new${e.originator === 'local' ? 'breathe' : 'incoming call'}`, e);
      const session = e.session;
      this.session = session;
      const peerconnection = session.connection;
      if (e.originator === 'local') {
        peerconnection.addEventListener('addstream', (event: any) => {
          console.log('InApp Caller ------>', event);
        });
      } else if (e.originator === 'remote') {
        console.log('remote test...........', session);
        store.dispatch(setInCallStatus(true));
        session.on('peerconnection', (data: any) => {
          console.log('this is peer-data-=-=-', data);
          data.peerconnection.addEventListener(
            'addstream',
            async (err: any) => {
              // set remote audio stream
              console.log('audiostream test ------', err);
            },
          );
        });
        console.log(
          'addstream test...........',
          session.remote_identity,
        );

        const callers = session.remote_identity.uri.user;
        emitter.setCallinStatus.call([true, callers]);
      } else {
        console.log('i am now iconmming call');
        const callers = session.remote_identity.uri.user;
        emitter.setCallinStatus.call([true, callers]);
      }

      // Failed to answer
      session.on('failed', (mdata: any) => {
        emitter.setCallinStatus.call(false);
        store.dispatch(setCallStatus('failed'));
        this.init();
        log('Reject the call or hang up before answering the call');
      });

      // Answered successfully
      session.on('accepted', (response: any, cause: any) => {
        log('Answered successfully');
        store.dispatch(setCallStatus('accepted'));
      });

      // Hang up after answering successfully
      session.on('ended', () => {
        log('the answer is over');
        emitter.setCallinStatus.call(false);
        store.dispatch(setCallStatus('ended'));
        this.init();
      });

      // call is hung up
      session.on('hold', (data: any) => {
        const org = data.originator;
        if (org === 'local') {
          log('The call is hung locally:', org);
          store.dispatch(setHoldStatus({local: true}));
        } else {
          store.dispatch(setHoldStatus({remote: true}));
          log('The call is hung up remotely:', org);
        }
      });

      // call is resumed
      session.on('unhold', (data: any) => {
        const org = data.originator;
        if (org === 'local') {
          log('The call is continued locally:', org);
          store.dispatch(setHoldStatus({local: false}));
        } else {
          log('The call is continued remotely:', org);
          store.dispatch(setHoldStatus({remote: false}));
        }
      });
    });
  }

How to trigger incoming call event here? Or what needs to be done?
